# Changing the input of a form field based on the data inserted at another input field

Tags: javascript, forms, nuxt.js

I have a booking app. In this app I have a form for selecting the city of departure and the city of arrival. It's international only, so if I pick a city from Ungaria, the recommended cities in the next input of the form, where I choose the arrival city, should be all the cities in the database except the ones from Ungaria. I access the database using axios and the app is created using NuxtJs.

How can I get in the second input all the cities except those that are part of the country of which the city selected in the first input is part?

This is the code for the dropdown lists of the inputs:

```html
<template>
  <div class="dropdownList">
    <label class="formLabel">{{ label }}</label>

    <input
      ref="dropdowninput"
      v-if="Object.keys(selectedItem).length === 0"
      v-model.trim="inputValue"
      class="dropdown-input"
      type="text"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
    />

    <div v-else @click="resetItem" class="dropdown-selected">
      {{ selectedItem.name }}
    </div>

    <div v-show="inputValue && apiLoaded" class="dropdown-list">
      <div
        @click="selectItem(item)"
        v-show="itemVisible(item)"
        v-for="item in itemList"
        :key="item.name"
        class="dropdown-item"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: {},
      inputValue: "",
      itemList: [],
      apiLoaded: false,
      apiUrl:
        "***"
    };
  },
  props: ["placeholder", "label"],

  mounted() {
    this.getList();
    this.filteredCities();
  },

  methods: {
    filteredCities() {
      let filtered = this.itemList.filter(res => res.countryCode != "ro");
      return filtered;
    },
    getList() {
      axios.get(this.apiUrl).then(response => {
        this.itemList = response.data;
        this.apiLoaded = true;
      });
    },

    itemVisible(item) {
      let currentName = item.name.toLowerCase();
      let currentInput = this.inputValue.toLowerCase();
      return currentName.includes(currentInput);
    },
    selectItem(theItem) {
      this.selectedItem = theItem;
      this.inputValue = "";
      this.$emit("on-item-selected", theItem);
    },
    resetItem() {
      this.selectedItem = {};
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.dropdowninput.focus());
      this.$emit("on-item-reset");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

My data in the database looks something like this

[image]

Comment: So, what is the question here?

Comment: Btw, you should probably use https://axios.nuxtjs.org/ if you're using Nuxt.

Comment: And `asyncData()` or `fetch()` (pick one) as a lifecycle to fetch your data. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching

Comment: Thank you for the additions. I modified the text a little :)

Comment: You do filter them into `filtered` no? If so, you can loop on them no?

Comment: Yea, i filter them there, but it's kinda hardcoded because I insert by hand the countryCode "ro". I want to insert it dinamically, based on the first input field.

Comment: Did you tried `this.itemList.filter(res => res.countryCode != this.inputValue)`?

Comment: Yes, it did not work

Comment: Because you need to trigger the function again with an `@input` or a `watch` otherwise the function will not recompute the data.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please :) ? I am learning Nuxt and Vue and I don't have any kind of any experience. 
I separated the component in two. One is DropDownList.vue and the other one is SecondDropDownList.vue. They are basically the same, the only difference is that in the second one I'll implement a function that takes the input value of the first component, checks the countryCode and returns all the citites except the ones with the precedent countryCode.
Now I struggle to acces the countryCode of the first component and check it in the second one. I think i should do it via props.

Comment: I just gave a simple and naive solution with a fake API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a naive and simple way of handling a dynamic fetching on some API from a variable located on the parent's input.

`test.vue` (a page)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Here, you can input either 'todos', 'albums' or 'photos' (this one is a bigger query)</p>
    <input v-model.lazy.trim="selectedEntity" type="text" style="border: 2px solid hsl(0, 100%, 50%)" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <child :selected-entity="selectedEntity"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedEntity: '',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`Child.vue` (component)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Here are all the available results:</p>
    <hr />
    <div v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">
      {{ result.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    selectedEntity: {
      type: String,
      default: 'todos',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.results = await this.$axios.$get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${this.selectedEntity}`)
  },
  watch: {
    async selectedEntity(newValue) {
      console.log('newValue >>', newValue)
      await this.$fetch()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It is triggered upon `change` event so you need to write in the input and then, click out of it (this can of course be refined).